# How can I extract market themes using an algorithm?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

For example, "Trump tax cut" is a big theme after Trump got elected. How can I extract such themes programmatically, and how can I link the theme to a portfolio that trades on this theme? (long exporters, short importers)

Comment: Reminds me of an interview I once read somewhere (?) with the late Fischer Black. He had once worked in Artificial Intelligence, so they asked him: Will AI be able to replace human traders? He said something like, I doubt it, because an algorithm would have trouble identifying the important themes, which are always changing. FWIW.